# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.builder Endpoints 2.0

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Java appengine version: 1.9.56
java: 1.8 
endpoints framework 2.0 
guava: 22.0
I have made the changes in web.xml from endpoints framework 1.0 to 2.0
I am using maven for build. Is new Google cloud tools plugin com.google.cloud.tools compulsory?
I am using appengine-maven-plugin, not cloud tools plugin
I got the following exception during /_ah/warmup.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.builder()Lcom/google/api/server/spi/SystemService$Builder;
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.createSystemService(EndpointsServlet.java:122)
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.init(EndpointsServlet.java:57)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:643)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:422)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:892)

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a dependency on the old Endpoints frameworks, still. Run `mvn dependency:tree` and look for occurrences of `appengine-endpoints`. If you see it, you need to remove it from your `pom.xml`.

Comment: I checked the dependency tree. It is not depending on old Endpoints.

Comment: What maven should be used?  is it appengine-maven or cloud-tools-maven. I am using appengine-maven.

Comment: cloud-tools-maven. That could be the issue.